# Pickle files blocking airflow DAG to see in dashboard with kubernetes executor

Tags: python, airflow, pickle, directed-acyclic-graphs, kubernetesexecutor

I put couple pickle files under  airflow DAG folder  and everything was working with local astro setup.  But when I deployed on remote cluster  which is using kubernetes executor Airflow is not able to find dynamic DAGs.

Is anyone have idea about it ?

I just want to understand the architecture behind kubernetes executor.  Why pickle files blocking dynamic DAGs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no  code.  As I said above  I put couple pickle file under airflow DAG folder and it is blocking dynamic DAGs  under kubernetes cluster